# Сохранить картинку на сервер

Tags: php

Ребят, всем привет!
столкнулся с такой проблемой - сохранение картинки на сервер

```
$file = 'http://img.lenagold.ru/m/mjach/mach01.png';
$newfile = 'mach01.png';

if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
    echo "не удалось скопировать $file...\n";
}
```

в таком формате все отлично сохраняет. 
А вот как сохранить картинку вот из такой ссылки? ни как не получается ( 
тупо не видит файла!!!

```
$file = 'https://ar4666.bitrix24.ua/bitrix/components/bitrix/crm.product.file/download.php?auth=&productId=13&fieldName=DETAIL_PICTURE&dynamic=N&fileId=119';
$newfile = 'mach01.png';

if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
    echo "не удалось скопировать $file...\n";
}
```

Comment: добавь ей расширение самостоятельно

Comment: так там авторизацию просят, потому и не видит.

Comment: @sbaikov а куда именно? можно пример?

Answer (score 2):

**В ссылке указан ID файла** `fileId=119`.

Вы можете получить этот файл с помощью API Bitrix.

Например методом [`CFile::GetByID`](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cfile/getbyid.php) .

Можно средствами API сразу [копировать файл](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cfile/copyfile.php) в нужное место с помощью метода [`CFile::CopyFile`](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cfile/copyfile.php).

Или получить путь к файлу с помощью метода [`CFile::GetPath`](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cfile/getpath.php) и передать путь к файлу так как вы делаете сейчас, в функцию `copy`.

*PS: Получить параметр запроса из строки можно так*

```
$url = 'https://ar4666.bitrix24.ua/bitrix/components/bitrix/crm.product.file/download.php?auth=&productId=13&fieldName=DETAIL_PICTURE&dynamic=N&fileId=119';
$parts = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
echo intval($query['fileId']);
```

Comment: У меня облако к сожалению, по этому пытаюсь через вебхук это сделать

Comment: есть мысли как из облака это сделать?

Comment: Решение этой задачи есть на форуме bitrix. https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/support/forum/messages/forum48/topic108843/message542387/#message542387

Comment: не понимаю, почему так происходит 
создал приложение в нем пишу - 

`$rsFile = CFile::GetByID(119);
echo $rsFile;`

ничего не показывает, хотя должно вывести путь от корня сайта к зарегистрированному файлу.

что опять с ним не так?

Comment: Ваш php скрипт расположен на этом же сайте? 
https://ar4666.bitrix24.ua/

Comment: нет, это облако и я кладу файлик к себе на хостинг, после создаю приложения и дергаю этот файл с хостинга